# Migrating to AndroidX does nothing on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

I want to migrate my existing project to androidx. For that, I am clicking Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX, and it asks me to backup my project, after doing that Android Studio searching and showing me Refactoring Preview. And when I click to Do Refactor, nothing happens. Neither trying to migrate, nor giving any error. I am using latest gradle version.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dummy"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

gradle.properties: (There is only one line)

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

Comment: Show your `gradle.properties`

Comment: The migration refactor command makes use of two flags. By default, both of them are set to true in your gradle.properties file : android.useAndroidX=true, android.enableJetifier=true , since in your case it didnt happend ?

Comment: @Ganesh Nope, it didn't happen.

Comment: @YSFKBDY, what the Gradle and wrapper version ?

Comment: @Ganesh, Gradle 3.4.3 and wrapper 5.1.1

Comment: @YSFKBDY all the factors are up to date when migrating in your case, so do 1 thing Invalidate cache and Restart and try to migrate.. this may help ..

Comment: It can't if you have compile error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add below in your **`gradle.properties`** section.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Read official documents about [**`Migrating to AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

### FYI

You can upgrade **`tools.build:gradle`** version

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

And

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "####"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
```

Then **`Restart IDE`**

Comment: Shouldn't Android Studio add those lines after the migration?

Comment: @YSFKBDY Yes, Kindly read https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Added those lines, sync the file, and tried to migrate again. Still does nothing. Only difference is now, most of my import lines are red.

Comment: thank you. Updating tools.build:gradle version solved my problem. Migrated to AndroidX successfully. Much appreciated.